# What is the purpose of the hole in the 12 x 12 boat bow (6051)?

Tags: piece-information

I recently received Renegade Runner (6268), and I noticed that it has a somewhat awkward hole in the bow:

[image]

The main bow piece has a hole for some reason, but I'm not sure what it is for. Here's [the part](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/6051c01):

[image]

As far as I could tell, this is a list of all sets which use this part:

- [6268](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6268-1)
- [6250](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6250-1)
- [6493](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6493-1)
- [6280](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6280-1)
- [6291](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6291-1)
- [6271](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6271-1)

In each of these sets, the hole in the front is simply left open. Is there some reason for this?

Comment: I would have thought it was simply supposed to mimic the anchor hole, but since 6280 has an anchor and it's not even attached through there, it's not a really good explanation

Comment: Looks like an anchor hole to me too. Now I really want a copy of 6493.

Comment: Well, it looks too small for canon. Perhaps the piece designer intended it as an anchor hole, but the set designers didn't use it that way? Perhaps it was modelled on a real ship's bow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't intend to answer my own question, but after reading through the comments and doing some more digging, I think it is clear that this was intended to be a [hawsehole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawsehole) (hole that the anchor rope passes through).

The 12 x 12 boat bow in question is a chronological descendant of the [16 x 12 boat bow](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/2557c01):

[image]

That larger part was created with the launch of the Pirates theme in 1989 and was used in the two flagships of that time: [Caribbean Clipper (6274)](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6274-1) and [Black Seas Barracuda (6285)](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/6285-1). Carribean Clipper clearly uses that hole for the anchor rope:

[image]

The 12 x 12 bow didn't appear in a set until 1992, so my best guess is that this hole was included to match the earlier part, but set designers ended up not actually using it for that purpose.